# significado de redim no asp clássico

Tags: asp

O que significa isso?

```
redim preserve VetRede(iCont)
```

VetRede é uma variável declarada no asp(coloquei isso, senão o corpo da pergunta fica fora dos padrões, poucas palavras), eheheheh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O construtor `redim` redimensiona um array em tempo de execução.

É importante que conheça também o `preserve` que é usado para preservar valores existentes.

```
redim preserve array()
```

O `preserve` não é obrigatório, mas é bom saber para quando precisar.

De um modo prático

```
dim VetRede(5) ' Declara um array com 5 índices

redim VetRede(15) ' Redimensiona o array existente para suportar 15 índices.

redim preserve VetRede(15) ' Redimensiona o array existente preservando dados que porventura possam existir.
```